# Xamarin.Android: TextView text doesn't change after Task.Delay() c#

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I am trying to change the text of a TextView after some delay. I have written a method which is called after some operation is performed.

```
public void Update()
{
      Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            dotsLoaderView.Hide(); // This works fine
            imgOverlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;  // This works fine
            ll_Info.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;  // This doesn't work
            txt_Info.Text = "Some mesage !";  // This doesn't work
        });
}
```

Where `ll_info` is the id of a linear layout which contains the textview of id `txt_info`.
I have reviewed my `layout.xml` file, there is no collision in android:name tags, each and every id are different. As when I change the text of this textview from any other place, it works but when I am trying to change inside `Task.Delay()`, it's not working. Why?

Answer (score 1):

View updations must be done on UI thread. 
Try:

```
public void Update()
{
    Task.Delay(10000).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        dotsLoaderView.Hide();
        RunOnUiThread(delegate
        {
            imgOverlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            ll_Info.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible; 
            txt_Info.Text = "Some mesage !";
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: No exceptons raised in VS, nevertheless, updating never happens =(

Answer (score 1):

Update the method to use async to allow for easier continuation.

```
public async Task UpdateAsync() {
    await Task.Delay(10000);//Non blocking delay on other thread
    //Back on the UI thread
    dotsLoaderView.Hide();
    imgOverlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    ll_Info.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    txt_Info.Text = "Some mesage !";
}
```

and have it called in a raised event's handler

```
public async void Action(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await UpdateAsync();
}
```

Or have every thing done in the event handler

```
private event EventHandler Update = delegate { };

private async void OnUpdate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    await Task.Delay(10000);//Non blocking delay on other thread
    //Back on the UI thread
    dotsLoaderView.Hide();
    imgOverlay.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
    ll_Info.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    txt_Info.Text = "Some mesage !";
}
```

You register the event handler with the event

```
Update += OnUpdate;
```

and directly after the operation is performed raise the event

```
Updated(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```